# Intuition behind relation of expected value of conditional probabilities and marginal probability distribution

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I have been trying the following question; If you help with any intuition I would be very appreciated.

$\displaystyle p_{X}(x)=\int _{y}p_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y)\,p_{Y}(y)\,\mathrm {d} y=\operatorname {E} _{Y}[p_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y)].$

I tried to infer from classical expected value equation of a continuous random variable which is probability weighted average of all the possible values;

${\displaystyle \operatorname {E} _{Y}[y]=\int _{y}y p_{Y}(y)\,\mathrm {d} y.}$

I can intuitively easily understand the multiplication of a "value" with it's corresponding probability value. However, when it comes to interpret the first equation, I do stuck at imagining multiplication of 2 distributions...

Comment: Have you tried to consider a discrete example. For example, what is the probability to first throwing a coin and to get *head* and then rolling a dice and get $6$. Next, you can make things more complicated by inducing dependence: First you throw six coins and count the *heads*. Then you role as many dices as you had *heads*. What is the probability do get at least one $6$?

Comment: The *distributions* aren't multiplied: their densities are. This multiplication works exactly like multiplying any two functions.  (There's a technical nicety involving Lebesgue integration: the densities aren't actually functions; they are *equivalence classes* of functions modulo changes on sets of measure zero. But the product is still well defined as an equivalence class, essentially because the union of two sets of measure zero still has measure zero.)